# problems understanding how to get real X/Y of ImageView

Tags: java, android

I have a RelativeLayout placed on my activity (extends Activity). The image represents the layout.

[image: plane]
<sub>(source: [kmnw.ru](http://kmnw.ru/pvt/planexybug.png))</sub>

The misunderstanding goes in values that  i am getting from ImageView (later 'Plane', that draws white plane).

I am setting x/y of plane using `setX()` and `setY()`.
But later when i got x/y from plane to draw radar/fuel circle i am getting not exact values (as you can see rectangle shows position of imageview if using getX()/getY()). Also when plane is almost top/left it shows real values, but going to right/bottom will fully desync  real X/Y and x/y that i am getting using `getX/Y()` .
I tryed using scale value (yes the plane is scaled to 0.7), getting bounds with `Plane.getDrawable().getBounds();` or using `getLocationOnScreen()`, nothing works fine.
The circle is positioned now using:

`c.drawCircle((float) Plane.getX() + Plane.getWidth() / 2, (float) Plane.getY() + Plane.getHeight() / 2, 120, p);`

The rect is drawed using:

`c.drawRect((float) Plane.getX(), (float) Plane.getY(), (float) Plane.getX() + Plane.getWidth(), (float) Plane.getY() + Plane.getHeight(), p);`

Also i use rotation of `imageview` (to change plane angle) if that matters.

Looks like i am getting now correct Y after i changed ActivityBar to Activity. 
This means i needed just to subtract the ActivityBar height from getY(). But the problem with X is still active and there is no padding/margin at left/right corners of layout.

Comment: Use ImageView.getImageMatrix()

Comment: thanks pskink, what then i should use to get x/y?

Comment: map the point using returned Matrix

Comment: pskink can you please show example with java code or point me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dividing height by -3 solves problem